# Is this diagram correct?

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

The question was to draw a diagram for a proof. There are 7 statements named by numbers from 1 to 7. If any of the statements are proven then a theorem X is proven. There is equivalency between 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 3 and 7, 2 and 6, 1 and 5, 5 and 4.

My diagram looks like this $1 \Leftrightarrow 2 \Leftrightarrow  3 \Leftrightarrow 7$, $1 \Leftrightarrow 2 \Leftrightarrow 6$ and $1 \Leftrightarrow 5 \Leftrightarrow 4$ but how do i know if i have proven every direction? my guess is that since $ 7\Leftrightarrow 1\Leftrightarrow 6\Leftrightarrow 1\Leftrightarrow 5\Leftrightarrow 4$ we know that the diagram proves every direction.

Comment: I think you should draw your diagram two-dimensionally. i.e. you might draw the digits 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 in a circle, like a clock. Then the arrows might be neater to see

Comment: @311411 i did that but the professor told me i was wrong

Comment: hmm, then maybe professor provided a worked example you could mimick? Not sure what is desired, i never got a homework assignment like this exactly.

Comment: @311411 Thank you very much.

Comment: By the transitivity of $\Leftrightarrow$, as stated each statement should be equivilent to each other statement. Perhaps there's a "link" which was only proven in one direction?

Comment: @Angelica i checked again and there is no one way implication